# Unable to install rabbitmq due to not meeting dependencies: libssl

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, erlang, ubuntu-18.04, libssl

I want to install rabbitmq on my Ubuntu 18.04. I have been following the official [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html). However, my installation is not completed as I am getting stuck on the step: `sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server -y --fix-missing` as I face an error: unmet dependencies.

I tried installing libssl and then erlang-crypto, didn't work. I also installed `aptitude` using which I tried installing `erlang-crypto`, it also didn't install any package.

The command that I am running is:

```
sudo apt-get install -y erlang-base \
                        erlang-asn1 erlang-crypto erlang-eldap erlang-ftp erlang-inets \
                        erlang-mnesia erlang-os-mon erlang-parsetools erlang-public-key \
                        erlang-runtime-tools erlang-snmp erlang-ssl \
                        erlang-syntax-tools erlang-tftp erlang-tools erlang-xmerl
```

I get a failure message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 erlang-crypto : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The `libssl` package isn't available and I have successfully installed `libssl-dev`.

I expect to completely install RabbitMQ and it runs successfully.

Comment: Really weird. I tried on fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 and the command
 apt-get install rabbitmq-server -y --fix-missing 
worked with no problems and I got running rabbitmq server.
There may be some versions mismatch in packages previously installed on your system.

Comment: I installed rabbitmq on ubuntu 18, mint 18 and raspbian without any problems. If you're unable to solve the problem you could try docker. https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this same error on 16.04 when installing rabbitmq. I fixed this by adding the following lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian xenial erlang-21.x
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian xenial main
```

Afterwards, run:

```
sudo apt-get update -y 
sudo apt-get install -y rabbitmq-server
```

If you want to do the same on 18.04, you add the same lines except change "xenial" to "bionic".

I got this information from RabbitMQ documentation: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#apt-bintray

Comment: Doesn't work anymore since bintray has been sunset.